# Are any unvocalized versions of the Masoretic Text available, online or otherwise?

Tags: hebrew, hebrew-bible, masoretic-text

I have been looking for some time for a version of the Hebrew Old Testament text that removes the vocalizations that were added in the Masorah.  I would think that such a text would be more representative of the original Hebrew manuscripts.

Does anyone know whether such a text might be available?

Comment: The Torah scrolls used in synagogues do not have diacritics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[tanakh.us](http://tanakh.us/) has an option to remove the vocalisations: once you're viewing a passage, use the 'Content' dropdown to select the 'Consonants' option.

[image: Tanach.us screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Try www.mgketer.org. It's the Rabbinic Bible online. It presents the Aleppo Codex with Targums and commentaries. From the home page, click on תנך in the middle, and then עיון.

[image: Mikraot Gedolot Haketer home page]

You'll get the first chapter of Genesis. Up in the left-hand corner you should see a menu that looks like this:

[image: Reading Menu]

Click on the item תיקון קוראים. It should give you a column next to the text itself that shows the text without any vowels or accents - as it is written in the Aleppo Codex.

[image: Genesis 1]

Using the menu item ספר you should be able to get to any book of the Old Testament, and using the menu item פרק you should be able to get to any chapter.